# C++ Pass template argument through multiple functions

Tags: c++, templates

Consider these lines of code. When I try to compile the compiler will show errors like `'a' is not a member of 'DataType1'`. I understand how the compiler treats these as errors but is there any way I could avoid this or another method that works?

```
struct DataType1 { public: int x; };
struct DataType2 { public: int a; };

template <class E>
bool job2(E* newData, const int i){
  int something = 2;  
  if (i == 1) newData->x = something;
  if (i == 2) newData->a = something;
}

template <class E>
bool job1(List<E>* dataBase){
  E* newData = new E;
  job2(newData, 1);
  dataBase->push_back(newData);
}

template <class E>
int main(){
  List<DataType1>* dataBase = new List<DataType>;
  job1(dataBase);
}
```

Comment: You can turn the `const int i` variable into a template argument and specialize the templated function. But that brings a question: why don't you remove the `i` argument and just specialize on `E`?

Comment: Another way could be to define a set function with the same name (`SetI()`) in each `DataType` struct and call that instead `newData->SetI(something)`.

Comment: If you can use C++17, and if you can pass `i` as template parameter, you can use `if constexpr`

Comment: @freakish I tried overloading with job2(DataType1* newData) but it couldn't compile with error ```cannot convert argument from E* to DataType1```

Comment: @HàHuyLongHải that's because you try to `push_back` an element of type `E*` to `List<DataType1>`. That's obviously wrong, even when `E=DataType1`. The problem is `job1` function, not `job2` specialization/overload. Not to mention that `job1` leaks memory.

Comment: @HàHuyLongHải Have a look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/QxsRc8

Comment: @freakish this is my full code: http://ideone.com/EfXLJU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have C++17 at hand you can write:

```
template <class E>
bool job2(E* newData){
  int something = 2;  
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<E, DataType1>) 
     newData->x = something;
  else 
     newData->a = something;
}
```

and discard `i` alltogether (if you only used it to distinguish between types).

Othwerwise, what argues against simply overloading your function?

```
bool job2(DataType1* newData){
  commonOperation();
  newData->x = something;
}

bool job2(DataType2* newData){
  commonOperation();
  newData->a = something;
}
```

where `commonOperation` is everything the functions have in common.

Comment: I tried the second one but it couldn't compile with error ```cannot convert argument from E* to DataType1```